# Methods of Amplifying Poor Audio from Camcorder Recording?

Tags: software, editing

I have a recording from a camcorder (with a broken mic) where the audio is 1) largely white noise and 2) almost in-audible sound from people chatting in a room.

What methods could be used to amplify the "almost in-audible" parts (and remove the white noise)?

I guess what consumer level audio tools could do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your description of the audio, it is going to be hard to fix, as white noise tends to cover a very broad frequency spectrum and so is hard to get rid of without losing what you want to keep.
A decent starting point for you would be to use a freeware audio editing program like [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/). Here is a [noise removal tutorial using Audacity](http://wiki.audacityteam.org/index.php?title=Noise_Removal).

You can also use audacity to cut out sections where there is no background talking. Then you can use an effect called a **compressor** to attempt to raise the level of the speaking to a better level, although you may still find you are amplifying some background noise. Here's a description of the [audacity compressor](http://wiki.audacityteam.org/wiki/Compressor).